# Jubula on linux(Centos 7)

Tags: java, linux, jubula

Jubula AUT connection error on linux(Cent os 7). AUT agent starts successfully. When AUT is started with "autrun" it gives the error-
"**AUTs syserr: Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: "-javaagent:/home/virtusa/jubula_8.4.1.123/ite/plugins/org.eclipse.jubula.rc.common.agent_5.0.0.201701111513.jar**"

but it loads the AUT and cannot run tests on it

When AUT is started from Jubula UI again it load the AUT and gives the error 
"**Connection to AUT could not be established**" 
AUT cant be used to run tests or in object mapping mode.

AUT Intellij IDEA (plugin testing)
Jubula version 8.4.1.123

Answer (score 1):

The .rc. in the jar's name stands for Remote-control, it is necessary for Jubula to connect to an AUT.

Your program probably could not find or start the plugin. Make sure the .rc-jar is included in your launch-config and it's started at least run-level 2. (From RCP 4.x it became kind of lazy and it's necessary to specify this ever-since)

Comment: Thanks for the help